# How can I store a datetime value in my Magento database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento, backend

I am facing an error with storing date in the MySql database from my Magento backend module. I don't know why it happens only to me(the same code run smooth in my friend's backend).
I am upto the save()- option in the saveAction(), and I can also see the date(like

> `'created_time' => string '2014-09-13 13:41:15'` (length=19))

if I dump before save(). But it saves the null value in the table as:

> 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Please ..I am waiting for your answers. Thank you.
Please notice: it is nothing about the syntax or logical errors.

Comment: This is not much information to work on. Can you log the actual query?

Comment: I am asking if there is any possibility that my magento could not recognize this time format (2014-09-13 13:41:15) ..??

Comment: If this is a newly created database column on an extension of your own, it may be that Magento just has the description to the database table cached (this can occur even if all caching is disabled under System -> Cache Management). To see if this is the case, simply delete the entire 'var/cache' directory.

Answer (score 0):

on mysql datetime format this has helped me:

```
$rec->addData(array('dt_something'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time())));
```